# Nested environment variable does not expanded

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch, environment-variables

I can't explain the below strange issue.
I have two system variables:

```
PYTHONHOME = D:\Tools\ISDC_Tools\Scripting\Python.2.7
PYTHONPATH = %PYTHONHOME%;%PYTHONHOME%\Lib
```

After creating a new cmd window, the `PYTHONPATH` variable does not expanded, but if I set the same value it already holds, the value "agree" to be expanded.

I wonder if 'delayed expansion' is the cause but as far I understand it's not related to this.

looking for explanation :)

[image: file]

Comment: How did you create those environment variables, exactly?

Comment: System properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Start `regedit.exe`, then navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment` if you set them as user variables, or to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` if you set them as system variables. Make sure the `PYTHONPATH` is of type `REG_EXPAND_SZ`.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I almost thought that the root cause was found. they are defined in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`, and indeed, they are defined as `REG_SZ`. BUT, I have created two new variables as `REG_EXPAND_SZ` and the same issue still appears :(

Comment: Make sure they aren't set as user variables too. Also, only `PYTHONPATH` should be `REG_EXPAND_SZ`, `PYTHONHOME` can be created as `REG_SZ`. After making the required changes, log off and log back on.

Comment: They aren't set as user variables, and PYTHONHOME was `REG_EXPAND_SZ` also. I have changed it to `REG_SZ` and it's still the same. I re-logged in now (and also before)

Comment: I too am seeing this behavior, but only when nesting REG_EXPAND_SZ references.  For example, `set A=FOO` `set B=%A%\BAR` `set C=%B%\ASD`.  The result is A=="FOO", B=="FOO\BAR", and C=="%B%\ASD".  Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not..